# MIME Type extraction on Codingame

Tags: python

I'm trying to solve a puzzle on codingame:

The goal is to extract the MIME-types of some strings like so
Input:

```
2
4
html text/html
png image/png
test.html
noextension
portrait.png
doc.TXT
```

Output:

```
text/html
UNKNOWN
image/png
UNKNOWN
```

My code is running smooth so far but at a longer list I get an error that my Process has timed out.
Can anybody hint me?

My code:

```
import sys
import math

# Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
# the standard input according to the problem statement.

n = int(input())  # Number of elements which make up the association table.
q = int(input())  # Number Q of file names to be analyzed.
mime = dict(input().split() for x in range(n))
fname = [input() for x in range(q)]

# Write an action using print
# To debug: print("Debug messages...", file=sys.stderr)

for b in fname:
    if '.' not in b:
        print('UNKNOWN')
        continue
    else:    
        for idx, char in enumerate(reversed(b)):
            if char == '.':
                ext = b[len(b)-idx:]
                for k, v in mime.items():
                    if ext.lower() == k.lower():
                        print(v)
                        break
                else:
                    print('UNKNOWN')
                break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know for certain that it's the reason for your code timing out, but iterating over your dictionary's keys and values to do a case-insenstive match against the keys is always going to be relatively slow. The main reason to use a dictionary is that is has `O(1)` lookup times. If you don't take advantage of that, you'd be better off with a list of tuples.

Fortunately, it's not that hard to fix up your dict so that you can use indexing instead of iterating to check each key manually. Here's the relevant changes to your code:

```
# set up the dict with lowercase extensions
mime = {ext.lower(): tp for ext, tp in (input().split() for _ in range(n))}

fnames = [input() for x in range(q)] # changed the variable name here, plural for a list

for filename in fnames: # better variable name than `b`
    if '.' not in filename:
        print("UNKNOWN") # no need for continue
    else:
        _, extension = filename.rsplit('.', 1) # no need to write your own split loop
        print(mime.get(extension.lower(), "UNKNOWN")) # Do an O(1) lookup in the dictionary
```

In addition to changing up the dictionary creating and lookup code, I've also simplified the code you were using to split off the extension, though my way is still `O(N)` just like yours is (where `N` is the length of the file names).

Comment: Thank you! Had to do make a minor change,

    fnames = [input().lower() for ....

for case insensitive lookup.